# Office.js - Office.context.ui.messageParent does not get call after protecting a sheet in dialog box

Tags: javascript, angular, office-js, exceljs

I am working on a project which has Office.js implementation.

In Excel, I am opening a dialog box on a protected sheet, adding some items which on turn invokes Office.context.ui.messageParent and insert items in new rows in sheet after unprotecting it, then again applies the protection to the sheet. If I again try to add items in the same dialog box, it is found that Office.context.ui.messageParent is not getting called thereby not inserting the new items anymore. But if I close the dialog and open it again, then adding the items in sheet works by calling Office.context.ui.messageParent. Also if I do not protect the sheet after inserting items and tries to perform the operation again then Office.context.ui.messageParent gets called all the time in dialog box.

When I am performing the same kind of operation for delete/edit operation by protecting the sheet, Office.context.ui.messageParent works all the time in the dialog box.

Please help as I am trying to debug the issue for quite some time now.

Comment: I don't understand your paragraph "When I am peforming ..." Please clarify what you mean. Thanks.

Comment: @RickKirkham From the same dialog box when I am deleting/editing the items Office.context.ui.messageParent works. After that, if I again try to delete/edit the item in the same dialog box(without closing it), Office.context.ui.messageParent continues to work.